# Angular HttpInterceptor does not work

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I'd like to implement a HttpInterceptor, but somehow, it's not doing anything at all.

Custom service implementing `HttpInterceptor`:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthenticationService} from "./authentication.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log("INTERCEPTED!!");

    const authHeader = this.auth.getAuthorizationHeader();

    const authReq = req.clone({setHeaders: {Authorization: authHeader}});

    return next.handle(authReq)
      .do((event) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log(event);
        }
      }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

Provided in `app.modules.ts`:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
      multi: true,
    },
    AuthenticationService
  ]
```

Unfortunately, it seems to be doing nothing. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out. To perform the `get()` call I still used `Http` from `@angular/http` instead of `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`.

Now it works fine.